# Deploying to specific container in AWS multicontainer docker environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk instance with Multicontainer Docker environment which have few apps deployed on different containers.

Currently if I want to update any one container, I have to upload the code for all the containers (including the old ones) as a zip to elastic beanstalk.

But I want to update the code for a specific app in a specific container without touching any other container. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Elatic Beanstalk with a elastic environment  you only can upload a zip with all of you container configuration files and aplications files because you cant edit a specific file or container configuration without upload a new zip file, because when your Elastic Beanstalk environment degrade or create new instance, the environment will load the original zip files that you uploaded previously, for tath reason you cant edit a specific file  or container configuration by FTP, SFTP ot anyone service that allows this action whitout upload a zip file with the applications files or container configuration files.

Comment: So, doesn't aws provide any provision for that?

Comment: You can't modify configurations  directly on elastic beanstalk, the another way to do this is you can create a continous deploy with jenkins and auto deploy to besnatalk when you need to change any configuration or file on your project

Comment: Even using that we need to have the source code that is deployed in other containers, in order to update some container.